# How to calculate the file size?

Tags: sql, database

For the following relation:

**purchase(purchaseID string(20), userID string(20), softwareID string(30), user_name string(30), sofware_title string(100), purchase_details string(100))**

Each character in a string is 1 byte long (i.e. purchaseID is 20 bytes).

Assume there are 80,000 records in the purchase relation and the block size is 3,000 bytes.

I need the following information:

a)  Calculate the file size in number of blocks assuming fixed length record structure is used for the file.

For questions b and c, assume the following query is given:

**“select * from purchase where purchaseID=1923”.**

1.b.    If the file is orderd by software_title, how many blocks in average need to be searched forthe given query?

1.c.    If the file is ordered by purchaseID, how many blocks need to be searched for the given query at worst case?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are not a homework writing service. Please read [ask]. Simply copying and pasting a homework assignment here will not get you the answers you are looking for. Work on your assignment to the best of your ability, and when you encounter a *specific* problem, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your table schema, one record in your `Purchase table` will take 300 bytes, assume that you are using `varchar`. and entire 80000 records will take `80000*300 = 24000000 B`, then divide it by 3000, which give you `8000` blocks. I guess it has the same meaning as `pages`?

For question B, it depends on whether you have indexes or not. And it is really hard to tell how many actual pages the engine has serached.

Same for your question C

Comment: A [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) is something entirely different.

Comment: sorry, I meant `page`, mess it with `code page` while I am working on ssis xD